# why does my direct traffic have 70% New visits

Tags: google-analytics

I thought direct traffic are people who type the website name or click the bookmark meaning they are returning visitors. but why does GA show 70% new visits in my direct traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks To [this forum](https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=135a104349f92732&hl=en)

In addition to:

- Typing in the URL in the browser
- Accessing from browser bookmarks

direct traffic can mean

- Accessing from links in email footers or newsletters without campaign identifications
- Accessing from links in office documents like Word, Excel, Powerpoint, or PDF documents
- Accessing via server or client redirects (301, meta refresh tags etc.) depending on server or browser settings
- Accessing from users in very security-restricted environments (no referers passed)
- as well - i.e. links from a variety of non-standard-webpage environments.

The [definition right from google](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/08/back-to-basics-direct-referral-or.html) is:

> "[(direct)[(none)] - Visitors who
>   visited the site by typing the URL
>   directly into their browser. 'Direct'
>   can also refer to the visitors who
>   clicked on the links from their
>   bookmarks/favorites, untagged links
>   within emails, or links from documents
>   that don't include tracking variables
>   (such as PDFs or Word documents)."

Comment: thank you sir! do you also have high bounces from your direct traffic?

Comment: other major sources of direct traffic are: https (https to http does not send referrers), twitter clients (in most cases, sometimes they send a fake referrer)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the new visits will also be over a time frame so they might not all be new, they are just new over the time frame set in your GA (mostly 4 weeks.)